# Extracting strings from mail log

Tags: email, log, postfix, grep, mail

I'm trying to extract all lines of text from mail log file that contain specific string (mail address). I know using `grep` will allow me to search for the address `mail.addres@example.org`, but how do I get it to print out the entire line that is containing `mail.addres@example.org`? That way I could easily scour vast ammounts of log files for precise information regarding `from` and `to` fields in order to find out with whom did the `mail.addres@example.org` have interactions.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Grep prints out the whole line containing the pattern. Please make more clear what you want. Post a sample text maybe.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep "mail\.addres@example\.org" filename.log
```

will print all lines containing `mail.addres@example.org`

Comment: Faster :P and +1

Comment: @A.B. But I do not see what the problem was

Comment: me too :), but the answer is simple

Comment: great, I can not even begin to think how did I manage to miss that :) solved!

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, using `awk`

```
awk '/mail\.addres@example\.org/' file.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearly quite late to the party here, sounds similar to what I have been learning. I use sudo because I don't access things as root but that's personal preference I guess:

```
sudo grep "mail.address@example.org" /path/to/file/mail.log
```

The output being plastered in the terminal (not ideal). I did find however that using redirection `>`:

```
> test.txt
```

Was a good idea. Yields the result with the command, bypass the output to the terminal window and put it straight into a file for me to open with notepad++ later. Something I did come across during my learning was the difference between one AND two angle brackets which was pretty handy:

```
>       # Overwrites destination file with current output
>>      # Adds current output to tail of file
```

Very handy when I don't want to keep creating new files for each search I do.

Comment: You don't need `sudo` (ie you don't need root privilege) to read most files, though I guess you might need it to read a mail log. Of course, running as root routinely is discouraged.

Comment: The problem with not using sudo is when I do need permissions, I was finding my commands were failing which was a pain in the behind. Most of what I am working on requires permissions so I find it a good habit. But, yeah worth pointing out for others reading this at a later date.

Comment: oh... using `sudo` for every command is nearly equivalent to running as root (i.e. a bad idea)... [principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege)